# Access the outer items of an object in a function of that object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, primereact

I've used `Dock` of [PrimeReact](https://primefaces.org/primereact/showcase/#/dock).

```
<Dock model={options.buttons} position="right"/>
```

According to its document, For `model` we should pass its `dockItems`.

So I defined `options` like this:

I have an array of objects. Inside it I have buttons, I want to check if the `xValue` doesn't have value then I show an error message.

```js
const options = [
        {
            xValue: '',
            uperMessage: 'Select a start date',
            lowerMessage: '',
            setMessage: function (time) {
                this.lowerMessage = `Selected start date: ${dateHelper.formatDate(time)}`;
            },
            buttons: [
                {
                    label: 'Next',
                    icon: () => <Button label="Next" className="p-button-success" />,
                    command: function () {
                        if (!this.xValue) {
                            toast.current.show({ severity: 'error', summary: 'Error', detail: 'Select a  start date!', life: 3000 });
                        } else {
                            setCurrentStep(2);
                        }

                    }
                },
                {
                    label: 'Cancel',
                    icon: () => <Button label="Cancel" className="p-button-secondary" />,
                    command: () => {
                        cancel()
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xValue: '',
            uperMessage: 'Select a end date',
            lowerMessage: '',
            setMessage: function (time) {
                this.lowerMessage = `Selected end date: ${dateHelper.formatDate(time)}`;
            },
            buttons: [
                {
                    label: 'Next',
                    icon: () => <Button label="Next" className="p-button-success" />,
                    command: function (xValue) {
                        if (!this.xValue) {
                            toast.current.show({ severity: 'error', summary: 'Error', detail: 'Select a Divergence end date!', life: 3000 });
                        } else {
                            setCurrentStep(3);
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    label: 'Cancel',
                    icon: () => <Button label="Cancel" className="p-button-secondary" />,
                    command: () => {
                        cancel()
                    }
                }]
        }];
```

How can I access the `xValue` in the `command` function?

If I use `this`, it gets the items of the current scope. How can I access the items of the parent?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need to send `xValue` as a parameter when executing `command` function

Comment: Could you please share this part of your code not as an image?

Comment: @Majid Mohammadi I updated my question, please check it

Comment: @fullstack I updated my question, please check it

Comment: Could you change the signature of command method? Or you should just use it as the sample?

Comment: How do you mean? Could you provide me a sample for changing the signature of the command method?
I think I should use it as the sample, but we can test the way you suggested.

Comment: @FatemeMirjalili I've posted an answer. Please check and try

Answer (score 0):

You can change `command` function and map on the `options` items, also `buttons` items. Finally you can find the current item and get the `xValue`  :

```
command: function () {
         let $this = this;
         options.map((option,oindex)=>{
             option.buttons.map(button,binex)=>{
                 if(button == $this)
                    if (!option.xValue) {
                           toast.current.show({ severity: 'error', summary: 'Error', detail: 'Select a  start date!', life: 3000 });
                    } else {
                        setCurrentStep(2);
                    }
            })
        })
```

Comment: thank you but it doesn't work. when I log the `xValue` in the `command` method, it returns an object of the current scope, not the `xValue`

Comment: I've updated my code, please try the updated one.

Comment: It doesn't work. It doesn't enter in the `if(button === $this)`

Comment: @FatemeMirjalili If you could create a executable sample of code in the sandbox or something like that, I will solve that for you.

Comment: @FatemeMirjalili I've tried this code and it works. Please see this link: https://es6console.com/krwa3ms0/

Answer (score -1):

you could use the array name "options" to access xValue like that
if(!options[item_index]['xValue']){
....
}
for example:- options[0]["xValue"] => // return ''